# Deploy lambda using serverless without worrying about node_modules

Tags: aws-lambda, serverless-framework, serverless

I would like serverless to deploy a nodejs lambda function, without taking 5-6 minutes in the packaging phase.

My package looks like:

```
package:
  exclude:
    - "**/*"
    - "*"
    - "!build/**"
```

My build folder is a combination of pre-built static assets and transpiled javascript code that I create and does not require any extra dependency resolution.  I simply want serverless to zip that folder and deploy it.

Comment: Did you consider using lambda layer to package your dependencies? then your lambda package will be very small

Answer (score 0):

I think you have use `include` option combined with your `exclude` option.

```
package:
  exclude:
    - "**/*"
    - "*"
    # - "!build/**"
  include:
    - build/**
```

You can use `serverless package -s dev` to see what has been zip before you decided deploy services to real world.